# Amazon load balancer with SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I have a web server running on an AWS EC2 instance. In an effort to support https on my custom domain (subdomain, to be precise), I have created a TLS certificate using the Amazon Certificate Manager. I am aware that the certificate will only be used once I use an additional AWS service such as the load balancing service, so I'm setting up a load balancer.

But I must be doing something wrong. I set up a listener on port 443 that routes to a target group on port 8080 (my server runs on port 8080, so I figured those two ports need to match).

I have a 404 handler on my site that I am trying to get to. So, say my custom domain is foo and the certificate was issued for sub.foo.com, then I am trying to access sub.foo.com/bar to get a 404 response.

When I do this over http, it works just fine:

```
$ curl http://sub.foo.com:8080/bar -v
*   Trying (...)...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sub.foo.com (...) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /bar HTTP/1.1
> Host: sub.foo.com:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 13
< Server: http-kit
< Date: Fri, 03 Jan 2020 17:03:36 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host sub.foo.com left intact
No such page.%
```

But when I try it over https, it fails:

```
$ curl https://sub.foo.com/bar -v     
*   Trying (...)...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connection failed
* connect to (...) port 443 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to sub.foo.com port 443: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to sub.foo.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Interestingly, if I try to access port 8080 directly over SSL, something different happens:

```
$ curl https://sub.foo.com:8080/bar -v
*   Trying (...)...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to sub.foo.com (...) port 8080 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: (...)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to sub.foo.com:8080 
* stopped the pause stream!
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to sub.foo.com:8080
```

Then again, that might just be because port 8080 is configured to work over http, not https.

As you can tell, there is a fair amount of guesswork involved here. I have been following the [AWS guide on how to create an https listener](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application//create-https-listener.html), but seem to be missing something. Once I set up the load balancer, the certificate is marked as "in use", so this is having *some* effect, but it's not sufficient.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `sub.foo.com` is pointing to your EC2 instance, not your load balancer.

When you curl `http://sub.foo.com:8080`, you're hitting port 8080 on your EC2 instance. Instead, what you want is to hit `https://sub.foo.com` (implied port 443) on your load balancer.

So you need to make a DNS change for `sub.foo.com` to point as a CNAME to your load balancer.

After you make this change, you'll need to wait for your DNS change to exceed it's previous time-to-live. While you're waiting, you can make a temporary `hosts` file change to test it.

Comment: Got it. Strangely, when I curl the load balancer's A-record directly, I get `curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name <a-record-here>`. Would making the DNS change fix that, or is this a separate issue?

Comment: Actually, the error message makes sense, because the certificate only works for the domain it is registered for, not the load balancer's domain. I have updated the CNAME and now when I do the curl I can see the handshake happening. I am now getting a 503 from an alleged server named "awselb/2.0", but I'm guessing that's unrelated to this particular question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: And, to anyone coming here from Google looking for an answer to that next problem I ran into: the EC2 instance was in an availability zone that I had not added to the load balancer's listener.